# How jQuery define object structure?

Tags: jquery, object, xml-parsing

Well, this issue is making me mad. I think that I have a lack of knowledge in this aspect.

I am trying to parse a XML response, everything is ok but the problem is when I try to access to objects. I treat them like arrays and I always receive "undefined":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <ajax-response>
   <response>
    <item>
      <name><![CDATA[ok]]></name>
      <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name><![CDATA[menuDiv]]></name>
      <value><![CDATA[Some HTML value]]></value>
    </item>
   </response>
  </ajax-response>
```

And here is the Jquery code:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $item = $xml.find( "item" );
        alert($item.length);
        $item.each(function(key, value){ 
            alert(typeof value);     
        });
```

This line `alert(typeof value);` returns "object". However, if I do `value[0]` or `$value[0]` it returns "undefined".

I would like to get "Some HTML value" from the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` object passed into your iteration function will be an XML DOM node, in your case an `Element` with the tag name `item`. So you'd retrieve information from it by getting attributes from it, or looking at the text in any child `TextNode`s that it has.

You can wrap the element in a jQuery instance and use jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to get attributes, and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get text.

> I would like to get "Some HTML value" from the object.

That would be `text` -- here's an example:

```
$item.each(function(key, value){ 
    var $value = $(value);
    alert(typeof $value.text());
});
```

---

Here's a full example that loops through the children of each `item`: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/iwonoq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/iwonoq/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var xml =
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' +
      '<ajax-response>' +
          '<response>' +
              '<item>' +
                  '<name><![CDATA[ok]]></name>' +
                  '<value><![CDATA[true]]></value>' +
              '</item>' +
              '<item>' +
                  '<name><![CDATA[menuDiv]]></name>' +
                  '<value><![CDATA[Some HTML value]]></value>' +
              '</item>' +
          '</response>' +
      '</ajax-response>';

  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      $item = $xml.find( "item" );
  display($item.length);
  $item.each(function(key, value){ 
    $(value).children().each(function(clave, valor) {
      display("$(valor).text() = " + $(valor).text());
    });
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

---

Or if you just want to grab the `value` that's the sibling of the `name` containing the text `"menuDiv"`, the relevant bit is:

```
var menuDivText = $xml.find("item name:contains(menuDiv)").next().text();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ipopug) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ipopug/edit)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I could access to another instance, but how could I get "Some HTML value" from that object? Because this would be usefull for the step in which I will take "Some HTML value". Now I am trying with: `$item.each(function(key, value){ 
   $(value).each(function(clave, valor){
    alert($(valor).text());
   });
  });` but it is returning both values: `<name><![CDATA[ok]]></name>
      <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
`

Comment: @LeandroCusack: `$(value).each(...)` loops through each `item` object in the matched set (so it loops once). If you want to loop through it's *child* nodes, use `$(value).children().each(...)`. Example: http://jsbin.com/iwonoq

Comment: Thank you,very good answer. The problem is that this is not associative, I pretend to select <value> content if <name> is "menuDiv". PHP rules in this aspect.

Comment: @LeandroCusack: I think you just need to spend some time reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com). It's hugely powerful.

Comment: @LeandroCusack: For instance, look at the final edit (at the end).